# Download of a HTML site including all resources Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, webkit

I would like to download a complete HTML site with all subresources. I know that this is possible with an off-screen instance of `WebView`, but this seems to be tricky.

`WebResource` needs an already downloaded site. All other classes I know, that provide a download, does not load subresources. I'm especially interested in (sub-)frames.

Is there a built-in mechanism (beside `WebView`) to download the entire site.

Comment: wget from command line

Answer (score 0):

Even I did not test it, because I do not need it anymore for some reasons, `WebDataSource` should do the job.